# Custom Isometric/Parallel Projection Grids

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, isometric, axonometric-projection

I found these attached designs online while looking for isometric illustrations. These designs are not on the standard isometric grid (30 degrees), rather they have different angles.

Has someone worked on such angle/grid before? What are they known as? How can to create custom grids and what things to keep in mind while designing one? What are some good sets of angles? Can anyone share some resources/tutorial/workflow around these?

Please note, I'm not talking about the standard 30-degrees isometric grid that everyone uses.

[image: from: http://dribbble.com/shots/3145041-Isometric-Data-visualization]

[image: From: http://stock.adobe.com/stock-photo/ananke-scene/120977783]

Comment: isometric or not, I suppose you can just create your own grid in illustrator with custom angles

Comment: You can find how to adapt SSR to custom angles [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67250/trimetric-cube-drawing-in-illustrator/67271#67271), these kind of views can be trimeric, axonometric or orthographic depending on th angles and th relationship beween angles and length. To busy right now but yes i do stuff like this all day long. PS: many games arent truly 30 degree angles as that would mean they need partial pixel angles

Answer (score 1):

*While this is not a direct answer, hopefully it gives you some ideas on where to start for when it comes to custom grids.*

## Terminology: Axonometric

There's some good info on WikiPedia: [Axonometric projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometric_projection).

> Axonometric projection is a type of parallel projection used for creating a pictorial drawing of an object, where the object is rotated along one or more of its axes relative to the plane of projection.
>
> The four types of axonometric projections are isometric projection, dimetric projection, trimetric projection, and oblique projection, depending on the exact angle at which the view deviates from the orthogonal.
>
> – [Axonometric projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometric_projection)

I have always liked this example image: [Comparison of several types of graphical projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometric_projection#/media/File:Graphical_projection_comparison.png):

[image]

(By SharkD - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=8497328)

### Example: 30º angles using custom guides

[image: iso]

In illustrator, you can draw a path, right click, and choose to convert it to a guide. This could work well if you specify construction guides at desired angles in preferences, and then copy/paste/duplicate your guides to create a custom iso grid. For example:

[image]

**Example preference:**

[image: prefs]

Or using [VectorScribe](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/)’s “protractor” panel:

[image: protractor]

Another example:

[image]

#### Using [Hot Door CADtools](https://www.hotdoor.com/cadtools)

[image]

One day I had some issues working with 45º and 30º axo/iso grids using CADtools 7, so I emailed their support:

**Question:**

> How do I set the CADaxonometric to work with 45º and 30º axo/iso grids? When I type in 45º in both 3d boxes, and click on a cube face, that doesn't seem to align my object to the 45º grid (for example).

**Answer:**

> That’s because the angles are in 3D, not 2D. In CADtools 7, as you know, we had 2D angle fields that would translate into 3D. We removed them due to time constraints (the calculations were very intense), but plan to add them back in CADtools 10. In the meantime, here are the 2D to 3D settings you can use:
>
> ```
> 2D      | 3D
> ------- | -------
> 45 x 45 | 45 x 80
> 15 x 60 | 21 x 42
> 15 x 45 | 27 x 31
> 15 x 30 | 34 x 23
> ```

I thought that was interesting.